# How to collect e-mail addresses from iPhone app users

Tags: iphone, app-store

I am designing an iPhone app for a non-profit organization, and they are interested in collecting e-mail addresses to use on marketing lists from people who download the app.

What are the options for collecting this?

1. Is it possible to get e-mail addresses from iTunes Connect? On page 24 of the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf), they mention: "If your apps have auto-renewable subscriptions, you can download contact information for customers who have elected to “opt-in” to personal information sharing." We are not using auto-renewable subscriptions though, so is there another way to prompt users to share their information and have it accessible through iTunes Connect?
2. I assume that Apple doesn't allow developers access to e-mail addresses of all users who download their apps, but I can't see it documented anywhere - is that correct?
3. Obviously, there is the option of "rolling our own" database and prompting users to submit their e-mail addresses in exchange for some incentive. Could the app call the user's e-mail address used in the Mail app or App Store by default?

Comment: Technically, you could leverage the iTunesMetadata.plist found in the directory outside of your application bundle, but I can't say I recommend it.

Comment: Thank god there is no way to collect email addresses w/o user permission! Make the user enter their email addresses voluntary and it even makes a better image for the non-profit organisation.

Comment: @Pfitz Okay, good. True, it is a request that could result in privacy concerns, so I will use this info to let them know that it can't be done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. No it is not possible to get the email from iTunesConnect other than with the `auto-renewable subscriptions`
2. You are correct.
3. No you can not call the Mail app for the e-mail address. Also, you can't make the email address a requirment. This is stated in the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#privacy).

There is no way to collect e-mail addresses other than to ask the users to optionally give them to you. You will also need to provide a privacy statement.